# Can SQLAlchemy handle multiple hostnames in the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, patroni

We have an HA product that uses two hosts for replicating data across multiple data centers. We use Patroni to manage the hand-offs while servers undergo maintenance. After an initial attempt to set up a connection string for SQLAlchemy to recognize that we have multiple plausible hostnames, we were able to figure out that everything following the first host's name was being ignored.

Here are the two attempts we made to set the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to have multiple hostnames:

```
postgres://db_user:db_password@hostname1,hostname2?target_session_attrs=read-write/db_name

postgres://db_user:db_password@hostname1,hostname2?target_server_type=master/db_name
```

Any help on this would be huge! Thanks for taking the time to give it a look.

Comment: You could instead set up for example HAProxy or such to always direct the connection to the current leader, or simply loop over the host names, create an engine, and test the connection (though this will cause trouble later when the leader changes...). Finally, there's always the option to pass a connection factory to engine, which then can do any kind of magic in order to produce the DB-API connections :)

Comment: This was our thought, but before we go down this rabbit hole, wanted to see if anyone had experienced this before and found a way to make it play nicely within the configuration of the SQLAlchemy() object.